# Executing a time consuming stored procedure on ASP.NET 2.0 + Sql Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

In one part of our application, we have to save some data. The saving of data takes some time and it could vary from few secs to few minutes. To handle this, so there isn't a sql time out we have following process in place.

**Note**: This is all setup by our DBA and this process is in use for several years without any problem.

**1:** Call a storedProcedure that places a job in a table. This stored procedure returns me a jobid. The input parameters to this sp is an exec statement to execute another storedprocdure with parameters.

**2:** Then I call another stored procedure passing the jobid, that will return the status of the job e.g. completed(true) else false + an error message.

**3:** I loop through step 2 for max 5 times with a sleep of 2 seconds. If the status returned is completed or there is some error, I break out of the loop. And after 5 times still the status in incomplete, I just display message that it's taking too long and please visit the page later (this isn't a good idea but so far the process has finished in about 2-3 times looping and not reached 5 times max but there are chances).

Now I am wondering if there is any better way to do the above job or even today, after several years, this is the best option I have?

Note: Using ASP.NET 2.0 Webforms / ADO.NET

Answer (score 0):

I would look into queueing the operation, or if that's not an option (sounds like it might not be) then I would execute the stored procedure asynchronously, and use a callback to let you know when it's finished.

This question might help:

[Ping to stored procedure to know execution completed in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347995/ping-to-stored-procedure-to-know-execution-completed-in-net)

Comment: Well, what gbs has in place sounds very much like some sort of hand-made "queue"... the job is "async" and he has a job id that he can poll to get the completion status.

Comment: @Lucero: You are right it is kind of a queue. James: Does the async method take care of timeout due to execution taking too long on Sql?